# vlookup "FALSE" returns 0 instead of cell value for some rows

Tags: excel-formula, return-value, vlookup

[Cells that I am retrieving information from: Stranding log full_YS oh crap.xlsx]Infostats - sites'!$H:$J)
(Site= Gamtoos River Mouth; Lat= 33°58'03.1"S, Long= 25°02'47.8"E)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21ksD.png)

[Row 1: Site= Gamtoos River Mouth;
Long: =VLOOKUP($Q58;'[Stranding log full_YS oh crap.xlsx]Infostats - sites'!$H:$J;2;0) (returns 0);
Lat: =VLOOKUP($Q58;'[Stranding log full_YS oh crap.xlsx]Infostats - sites'!$H:$J;3;0) (returns 0)
Row 2: VLOOKUP($Q59;'[Stranding log full_YS oh crap.xlsx]Infostats - sites'!$H:$J;2;0) (returns corresponding value of cell in Stranding log full_YS oh crap.xlsx]Infostats - sites'!$H:$J)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ9wv.png)

I'm using the vlookup function to retrieve GPS locations from a different document. Image 1 contains the cells I'm retrieving information from (Site= Gamtoos River Mouth; Lat= 33°58'03.1"S, Long= 25°02'47.8"E). The second image shows the formula that I'm using and 2 rows. The 1st row has the information from image 1 (Site= Gamtoos River Mouth) and I want to get the GPS locations in the Lat and Long columns. The second shows how the formula worked for another row.

Function: Long =VLOOKUP($Q58;'[Stranding log full_YS oh crap.xlsx]Infostats - sites'!$H:$J;2;0)
Lat =VLOOKUP($Q58;'[Stranding log full_YS oh crap.xlsx]Infostats - sites'!$H:$J;3;0)

I would like to know why the formula is working for some rows but not others and how to fix it?

I'm not sure how to add images yet, sorry.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are sure the relevant data exists in your spreadsheet and VLOOKUP is not catching it, take time to verify that the referenced cells don't have hidden spaces or non-printing characters. Also, ensure that the cells follow the correct data type.

You could try making at new data set in notepad og notepad++. import the data in a new excel sheet with the import guide in the data tab, make sure to set the correct data types for the coordinates. see if this solves the issue.

Another thing you could do is to use the =TRIM and =CLEAN functions on the data to debug the error.

Comment: Thank you, Christoffer. I have checked these parameters and it's still not working.

Comment: What format is the document you are importing from xls or xlsx?

Comment: I'm importing from xlsx to xlsx

Comment: I updated my answer give the last part a try

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not working either.

Comment: Hello without a sample of your data is hard but you can try switching from 0 to 1 as aprox match or try using xlookup.

Comment: I made another update try that

Comment: Hi, I can't switch from 0 to 1 because it has to be an exact match since there are similar names for different locations.

How do I add a sample of my data?

Comment: I tried to Trim and clean the names and I lost even more information (a lot more #NA where I had managed to retrieve the information)

Comment: Can you make a sample Excel online document, showing more than one example each of formulae that do work, and that do not work, and then share a link to that - without being able to query the text values directly (as this would permit) there can only be speculation